# How to solved in Laravel relations null value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

[image]Im tru to use to last version of laravel and i have small problem with Laravel relationship One to Many
Im try to connect products with categories

This is my code of Product model

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

this is my code of Category model

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

This is my code in controller

```
$products = Product::with('categories')->get();
    dd($products);
```

this is my code from migration files

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->string('keywords')->nullable();
        $table->string('price');
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->text('image')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    });

Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->string('keywords')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

If someone know how to solved this problem I'll be very grateful

Comment: `belongsTo()` returns a single record or `null`. The name `categories` suggests many (it's plural). Change the name to `category`, or change the method to `hasMany()` or `belongsToMany()`. You should never use a plural name for single records, or a singular name for multiple records.

Comment: [Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with a `_` followed by the name of the primary key column](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse). So I think eloquent is determinig that the fk is `categories_id` intead `category_id`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I thought it was based off the name of the Model, not the method. `Category` should be correctly mapped to `category_id`. Ah; maybe not, but the method name is wrong; should be `category()` not `categories()` for a `belongsTo()` or `hasOne()` method.

Comment: @TimLewis I agree that the method name should be `category` and not `categories` since it's a `belongsTo` relationship. I just copied what is in the documentation regarding One To Many (Inverse). Eloquent will take the "snake case" name of the owning model and suffix it with `_id` for hasMany and hasOne relationshps, but for belogsTo, will examine the name of the relationship method. The other thing I added to the comment is just a guess, it could also give an exception by not finding the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly relation comes with eager loading.
Please update your codes according to single usage

In Product Model

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

In Controller

```
$products = Product::with('category')->get();
dd($products[0]->category);
```

Comment: While `with()` is not related to the issue here, saying to remove it is just wrong. If you're loading all `Product`, then accessing a relationship, **you want to use `with()` to avoid an N+1 query execution issue**. `Product::with('category')->get();` is the correct syntax here.

Comment: Ok updated, I already know this, i just want to show this is not 'with' issue, this is singular plural issue

Comment: Yup; make sense. Just keep in mind, you can't use `->all()` after another call, you need to use `->get()` or you get the error "Call to undefined method Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder::all()", so again, the correct syntax is **`Product::with('category')->get();`**

Comment: :) this area is not as ide, so i just add with and it is working yay! :) I updated

Comment: Haha yeah, that's an easy error to make. Typically, I never use `::all()`, since it's not available once chained, and just stick with `::get()`, even for all records. Like `Product::get()` and `Product::all()` will return the same thing, but `Product::with(...)->all();` is an error, where `Product::with(...)->get();` is not :)

Comment: Thank you. I am very inattentive to such things.

Answer (score 2):

You are telling relationships name is `categories`, so laravel `belongsTo` will look `categories_id` instead `category_id`.

You can rename your relationships name as `category()` or 
give your relationships foreign key to laravel like this;

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id', 'id');
```